# 2 weak references to the same object show different info

Tags: c#, arrays, scope, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have a program in which I allocated an int array and want to check whether it will be garbage collected after I call `GC.Collect()`. In this program I allocate an int array `array1` and keep a `WeakReference` to it in order to check whether it's garbage-collected later. I have a method called `procedure` that allocates a new, local array in it (`array2`) and assigns `array2` to an input `temp` array passed by reference. This method also assigns weak references `ref1` and `ref2` to hold info about an input `temp` array and `array2`. When I call this method, I pass `array1` to it, so `array1` becomes equal to `array2`. Once I exit the method, I call `GC.Collect()` to force garbage collection. Debugger tells `ref1` and `ref2` still have `IsAlive` property equal to `true`. `ref3`, which is instantiated in the `main` function and references `array1`, tells that `IsAlive` property is `false` after garbage collection, so `array1` has already been garbage-collected.

Shouldn't `ref1`, which references `array1`, have `IsAlive` property equal to `false`, just as `ref3` (which also references `array1`) does?

```
static WeakReference ref1;
static WeakReference ref2;
static WeakReference ref3;

const int max_size = 10;
public static void procedure(ref int []temp)
{
    int[] array2 = new int[max_size];

    temp = array2;

    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
        array2[i] = i * 2;

    ref1 = new WeakReference(temp);
    ref2 = new WeakReference(array2);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int []array1 = new int[max_size];

    ref3 = new WeakReference(array1);

    procedure(ref array1);
    //array1 = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: ref1 references array2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've gotten confused between your *variables* and the *values* they point to. At the point you call `GC.Collect()`, `array1`, `ref1`, `ref2` are all pointing to the array created in procedure() (`array1` being the only strong reference alive).

Trace through your code manually keeping track of each value (the array created in procedure(), the array created in Main()), and which variable points to which at every point.

You'll see that at the point where you create the two WeakReferences in procedure(), temp and array2 point to the same value (the array created in the same method). The WeakReference created in Main() will be the only thing left pointing to the array created in Main(), since the `array1` variable will be changed to point to the other array by procedure() due to the `ref`.

Comment: I got what you mean. When I changed my code so that ref3 is instantiated after procedure() is called and is set to reference array1 which now equals to array2, I get all 3 weak references having IsAlive property equal to true.
My other question is - since array2 was declared in a procedure and goes out of scope by the time garbage collection is forced, shouldn't it be garbage collected? All these weak references have IsAlive property equal to true, so what they reference (array2[]) hasn't been garbage-collected.

Comment: By doing `temp = array2;` in procedure() (temp is a ref argument) you changed the variable declared in Main() to point to the array, which keeps it alive. Referenced values (like arrays) never "go out of scope" - only variables that refer to them.